# How to animate the color of a RaisedButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a `RaisedButton`. I want to **animate** it's color from **green** to **red**, and vice versa, every time the user clicks it.

How this could be done?

Comment: see `ColorTween`

Comment: I know ColorTween but I don't know how to apply it on the Raised Button. Can you give more details?

Comment: use `AnimatedBuilder` for example - as in answer below

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
class ChangeRaisedButtonColor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ChangeRaisedButtonColorState createState() => ChangeRaisedButtonColorState();
}

class ChangeRaisedButtonColorState extends State<ChangeRaisedButtonColor>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _colorTween;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    _colorTween = ColorTween(begin: Colors.red, end: Colors.green)
        .animate(_animationController);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _animationController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _colorTween,
      builder: (context, child) => RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Change my color"),
            color: _colorTween.value,
            onPressed: () {
              if (_animationController.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
                _animationController.reverse();
              } else {
                _animationController.forward();
              }
            },
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :)
Note: `super.dispose();` should be the last line of the `dispose` method override.

Answer (score 57):

You can use **[`AnimatedContainer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html)** as raiseButton child . and when color changed it will be animated!

```
RaisedButton(
        onPressed: null,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          color: pageIndex == 1 ? Color(0xFF4B4B4B) : Color(0xFFD8D8D8),
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        ),
      )
```

and its just a container so it can have child like text..

Comment: your (underrated and under-loved) answer proves how much easier have become coding with flutter!

Comment: Thank you so much! this is just what I needed and it worked great. Thanks to your answer I didn't even have to try the other more involved answer.

Comment: The answer above from @Andrey Turkovsky is better. For example one drawback using this method is the loss of the splash effect of the button when tapped.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on [Vahab Ghadiri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2719243/vahab-ghadiri) 's answer but i've applied some modifications around it to have a `child`, so it becomes easier to plug and play:

```
bool _isRed = true;
static const int ANIMATION_DURATION = 500;
static const int CIRCLE_RADIUS = 25;

AnimatedContainer(
  // AnimatedContainer is used to fade a circle when color is changed
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: ANIMATION_DURATION),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: _isRed ? Colors.red : Colors.yellow,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(CIRCLE_RADIUS)
    ),
  ),
  child: RaisedButton(
    child: Container(
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
    ),
  ),
// feel free to replace RaisedButton(..) with your preferred widget!
),
```

Then all what you need to animate color is to change the variable **_isRed** like this:

```
setState(() {
  _isRed = false; // or _isRed = false; (depends on your logic)
});
```