# Animate the color change when button is enabled or disabled

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a button whose color is Blue when enabled and black when disabled. What I want is, when I enable the button the color should gradually change from black to blue and not in an instant and vice versa. How can I do that?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53520649/6891637) could give you a basic idea

Comment: My button is a stateless widget. I don't want to write another 20 lines of code for a simple color change.

Comment: I'm more than a year late, but is there a solution for this even with the new ElevatedButtons? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use the AnimatedContainer, you build it once with a particular attribute when it's rebuilt with a different value using something like setState then it animates that colour. Or if the value is passed from the outside.

```
class AnimatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
 final Color widgetColor;

 AnimatedButton({this.widgetColor});

 build(){
  return AnimatedContainer(
   color: widgetColor,
   duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
   child: Text('Some text')
 );
}
```

You change _passedInColorValue either in setState or by passing in a different value from the parent on a rebuild and the container will perform the animation for you.

Comment: Can you please give a full example. I thought of using stateless widget but that doesn't seems to be possible.

Comment: @bnayagrawal If you want to keep track of the value in your widget then use a stateful widget, otherwise just use a stateless widget and pass your color in from the outside. I'm not gonna give a full example, but I'll add some more pseudo code it should be enough to give you an idea.

Comment: @bnayagrawal I editted the answer to show you the widget, just use that where you're using your color changing widget now, or just replace the container you have where you're changing your color with an AnimatedContainer. Shouldn't be hard to integrate if you have the color changing functionality in already. You just swap Container with AnimatedContainer and add a Duration.